# SQL Group by - Aggregate a column based on custom logic

Tags: sql, group-by

I have come across a case where I need to aggregate the table based on custom logic.

| Student_id | Subject | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Maths | FAILED |
| 123 | English | PASS |
| 456 | Maths | PASS |
| 456 | English | PASS |

Now I want the result in the following way:

| Student_id | overall_result |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | FAILED ( If a student failed in any subject, overall he is failed) |
| 456 | PASS |

Any idea how can I do this using SQL?

**EDITED**: Here can be other values also like GRACE , SUPPLYMENT. A student is passed only and only when all values are PASS, otherwise FAILED

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you please point out whether further values can appear in this column or "Pass" and "Failed" only? What to do if other text occurs?

Comment: @JonasMetzler : You are right, there can be other values also like `GRACE` , `SUPPLYMENT`. A student is passed only and only when all values are PASS, otherwise FAILED. Let me add this in the question also.

Comment: @Jens : I was able to group by `student_id` and `result` .. but I am not able to make further progress on how do I aggregate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your field "*Result*" allows only "*PASSED*" and "*FAILED*" values, you can use the aggregate function `MIN` to retrieve the smallest value between the two. If there's at least one "*FAILED*", it will get returned.

```
SELECT Student_id, MIN(Result)
FROM tab
GROUP BY Student_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8jekgzoG5mTZj3Qid1Pi2/0).

---

If you can have multiple values too, you can enforce any value different than "*PASSED*" to "*FAILED*", then get the `MIN` as per previous query.

```
SELECT Student_id, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN Result = 'PASS' THEN 'PASS'
                ELSE 'FAILED' 
           END) AS Result
FROM tab
GROUP BY Student_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8jekgzoG5mTZj3Qid1Pi2/1).

Comment: I have edited the question. Actually there can be many values in the result like `SUPPLEMENTRY`, `GRACE` etc ..

Comment: Updated my answer, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `COUNT` or `SUM` with `CASE`.

If the sum of `FAILED` values is > 0, this means the overall result will be `FAILED`, otherwise it will be `PASS`.

```
SELECT Student_id, 
CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'FAILED' THEN 1 END) > 0 
    THEN 'FAILED' 
    ELSE 'PASS' END AS overall_result
FROM tab
GROUP BY Student_id;
```

If we use MySQL, the above query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT Student_id, 
CASE 
  WHEN SUM(Result = 'FAILED') > 0 
    THEN 'FAILED' 
    ELSE 'PASS' END AS overall_result
FROM tab
GROUP BY Student_id;
```

Tested here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lKDv7e5C)